# F statistic for regression equation

Tags: multiple-regression, f-statistic

I was searching for some public material on *F-static* for multiple regression equation and come across with this link [https://www.statisticshowto.com/probability-and-statistics/f-statistic-value-test/#:~:text=The%20F%20value%20in%20regression,model%20has%20no%20predictive%20capability](https://www.statisticshowto.com/probability-and-statistics/f-statistic-value-test/#:%7E:text=The%20F%20value%20in%20regression,model%20has%20no%20predictive%20capability).

This says that

*The F value in regression is the result of a test where the null hypothesis is that all of the regression coefficients are equal to zero. In other words, the model has no predictive capability*

I am confused on the statement that all of the regression coefficients are equal to zero. Should not it exclude the *intercept* as one of the design coefficients?

Comment: Yes, it should exclude the intercept!

Comment: Read on: the very next sentence in your reference calls this "the intercept only model."